# jQuery Animate top (From bottom to top)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a Div a `top:275`.

I tried `.animate( {marginTop: -820 }` but on each screen it ends up to a different position. . .

So I changed the marginTop to `.animate( {top: 275}` but the div comes from the top to down (slidedown). Note that, so I can use the `animate:top` I had to set the div to `position:absolute` during the animation. . .

**Is there any hackyway to make the top come from the bottom up or make the marginTop have the same distance from the top on each screen resolution ?** ( I assume margintop can't be solved since im setting margin top to -820 in order to get at a point of top:275, therefore screens smaller than 1200px height, the div will go much higher...)

Here is my code:

```
$("#features").fadeIn()
            .css({
                position: 'absolute'
            }).animate({
                top: '275'
            }, function() { //callback });
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ah Found it!!

```
$("#features").fadeIn()
.css({top:1000,position:'absolute'})
.animate({top:275}, 800, function() {
    //callback
});
```

So basically I've set the top from css at the very end to 1000, then animated it to 275 which is up...

Comment: +1 fanks beastie!  I needed my dialog to slide down in a different way to slideDown().  I used :
  `var height = $dialog.outerHeight();
  $dialogPane.show()
   .css({top : height * -1})
   .animate({top : -1}, 400, function () {
    //callback
   });`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( '#features' ).show()
.css( {'opacity': 0, 'bottom': '-100px' } )
.animate( { 'opacity': '1', 'bottom' : 0 }, 1000 );
```

Comment: Have in mind that answers containing only code are not considered complete

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#btn-auto-refresh").show()
  .css({
    'opacity': 0,
    'bottom': '-100px'
  })
  .animate({
    'opacity': '1',
    'bottom': '100px'
  }, 1000);
```

```css
body{
min-height:1800px;
}
.auto-refresh-Div-position {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-auto-refresh {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  width: 36%;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom:-100px;
position:fixed;
}

.bgblue {
  background-color: #37A6E1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="auto-refresh-Div-position">
  <button class="pf bgblue btn-auto-refresh " id="btn-auto-refresh" style="display:none"><i class="ico ico-spinner11"></i><span class="ml10">New Deals</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.