# Grow/Reveal image from bottom to top

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to Grow/reveal an image from bottom to top?

The image I need to animate is an opaque PNG which is part of an animation sequence - the image is of a tower logo and I need to make it grow from base up.

This is the HTML -

```
        <div class="logoCover">
             <div class="logoTop">
             </div>
        </div>
```

I have set a fixed height on logoCover (height of the logo) and have tried animating height - but it always reveals from top down - any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026900/jquery-animate-top-from-bottom-to-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an absolutely positioned element reveal by "sliding up" if it is fixed to the bottom of its container.

```
.logoTop {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Note that `.slideDown` is the "reveal" method in jQuery, and `.slideUp` hides.  You still need to use `.slideDown` to reveal it even though it appears to slide up.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/UhNwB/