# reveal divs (with position:relative, in a vertical menu) from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown, slideup

(I've tried to be synthetic as possible in the thread's title)

So, basically, I have a vertical menu with buttons. When you click a button, a div shows up with jQuery's slideDown(), moving away what is under. If you click another button, another div appears, and the previous one closes with slideUp(). Everything is fine.

BUT

I want the divs to show from bottom to top. 
slideDown() reveals a hidden object from top to bottom... and I've tried jQuery UI "slide" with "up" property, but the problem is that it creates a placeholder firstly, and then shows the hidden content (here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/d9p0e250/4/) when I want to see it moving smoothly as with slideDown() and slideUp().
Here's the code:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li id="one">
        <button class="open">Button 1</button>
        <div class="box">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="two">
        <button href="#" class="open">Button 2</button>
        <div class="box">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="three">
        <button href="#" class="open">Button 3</button>
        <div class="box">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </li>
    <li id="four">
        <button href="#" class="open">Button 4</button>
        <div class="box">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.box {
width: 30%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
display: none;
}


#one .box {
background:red;
}

#two .box {
background:blue;
}

#three .box {
background:yellow;
}

#four .box {
background:green;
}

.open {
width: 30%;

}

ul li {
list-style:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
var open = $('.open'),
a = $('ul').find('button');

console.log(a.hasClass('active'));

open.click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this),
    speed = 500;
if($this.hasClass('active') === true) {
    $this.removeClass('active').next('.box').slideUp(speed);
} else if(a.hasClass('active') === false) {
    $this.addClass('active').next('.box').slideDown(speed);
} else {
    a.removeClass('active').next('.box').slideUp(speed);
    $this.addClass('active').next('.box').slideDown(speed);
  }
});
```

And the jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m34L3103/3/ 
To be more precise, taking this example, when I click a button I want to see first the line with "anim id est laborum", and in the last moment "Lorem ipsum..".

It's a subtle difference, 'cause the functions will be the same, but I'm working on a very specific UI based on images... and this is driving me crazy. I don't even know if it's something possible (in an elegant way). I hope there's a method, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: This is significantly harder than you might think.

Comment: that means the only way is to create tons of animations?

Comment: you will need to use an animation that does multiple things at the same time.  Plus, you've restricted us with "position relative" - which is unclear why it's necessary - but if so, this may not even be possible.  Lastly, you've indicated "slide up" - which to me means the bottom never moves, the top goes up the page.  You've defined it by saying "the text at the end appears first, and the text at the top appears last" - which is yet another twist.  So - honestly, it's a bit unclear what you want.  Can you clarify?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026900/jquery-animate-top-from-bottom-to-top

Comment: I need "position: relative" cause I have to absolutely position other divs inside the first one.

Comment: I know it sounds like a confused question, and I'm sorry. It's better to show than tell: I want the behavior of jQuery UI "slide"  with "up" direction, but without the initial "jump" of elements under (the first jsfiddle in thread provides an example https://jsfiddle.net/d9p0e250/4/)

Comment: Check the link I posted above in the comments.  That should get you going in the right direction.