# Scrolling to local anchor is scrolling backwards on second click

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create local anchor scrolling through my menu. I'm using links to go between anchors and javascript to scroll between anchors (I'm aware I can do that in html, but I can't seem to get this to work).

Once I one anchor link in the menu it works fine, but if I click it again it will scroll backwards to the starting point and I cant understand why.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 100
      }, 500);
      return false;
});
```

```css
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
html, body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px; 
  background: transparent; 
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: fixed;">
  <nav class="top-nav">
            <ul style="direction: rtl;">
              <li><a href="#service" style="cursor: pointer;">test</a></li>
              <li><a href="#gallery" style="cursor: pointer;">test1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">test2</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#!" id="burger-menu" onclick="toggleSideMenu()"><i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: white; font-size: 22px;"></i></a>
          </div>
        </nav>
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 700px;"></div>
<div id="service">
  Anchor 1
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 700px;"></div>
<div id="gallery">
  Anchor 2
</div>
<div style="margin-top: 700px;"></div>
<div id="contact">
  Anchor 3
</div>
```

I do believe the problem is related to having body and html scrolling attributes, but I do insist to keep the code this way because it's related to another part of my code.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/zYvwgqv) - If you click one of the menu child twice you will see the problem.

How can I fix the anchor link position and keep it scrolling smoothly?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to see what it is your trying to do, and can't seem to get the demo working. ANyway have you looked at affix https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#affix
That seems to be close to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @RichardHousham https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/zYvwgqv

Comment: Fresh look and I bet all those margin-top: 700px; are shoving the content down and maybe messing around with scrollTop It's not that clear.

Comment: @RichardHousham I have actually solved that with margin-top to fix the position of the div id, but the scrolling is still making those jumps backwards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that should work - credit to [jQuery Animate top (From bottom to top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026900/jquery-animate-top-from-bottom-to-top) 
For that code.

```
<style>

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
html, body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px; 
  background: transparent; 
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.fixed {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;

}

</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      $('.fixed').hide();

      $($.attr(this, 'href')).fadeIn()
        .css({top:1000,position:'absolute'})
        .animate({top:100}, 800, function() {
            //callback
        });
/*    
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $
      }, 500);*/
      return false;
});
</script>
<div style="position: fixed;">
  <nav class="top-nav">
            <ul style="direction: rtl;">
              <li><a href="#service" >test</a></li>
              <li><a href="#gallery" >test1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">test2</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>
        </nav>
</div>
<div id="service" class="fixed">
  Anchor 1
</div>
<div id="gallery" class="fixed">
  Anchor 2
</div>
<div id="contact" class="fixed">
  Anchor 3
</div>
```